# Making SQL Table row into Column

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to make a Query that will return a set of Columns with Values, this is what I'm getting at the moment,

```
╔═══╦═══════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ProgramTypeName║  TypeAmount ║
╠═══╬═══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Center        ║      4      ║
║ 2 ║ School        ║      2      ║
╚═══╩═══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I'm getting the ProgramTypeName from a Table, while the TypeAmount, Count(ProgramTypeName).

I'm trying to get to this point,

```
╔═══╦═══════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║Center         ║  School     ║
╠═══╬═══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║       4       ║      2      ║
╚═══╩═══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Any ideas on what I can do to achieve this?

@Indian This is the result I'm getting from your suggestion,

```
╔═══╦═══════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║Center         ║  School     ║
╠═══╬═══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║       NULL    ║    NULL     ║
║ 2 ║       NULL    ║    NULL     ║
║ 3 ║       NULL    ║    2        ║
╚═══╩═══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

When querying for the data normally I have this,

```
╔═══╦══════════╦═════════════╦════════╦════════════════╦═══════╗
║   ║License   ║  ProgName   ║ Id     ║ProgramTypeName ║Amount ║
╠═══╬══════════╬═════════════╬════════╬════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 1 ║ 45871    ║ TestName    ║  1     ║ Center         ║ 4     ║
║ 2 ║ 45871    ║ TestName    ║  1     ║ School         ║ 4     ║
║ 3 ║ 45871    ║ TestName    ║  1     ║ Other          ║ 2     ║
╚═══╩══════════╩═════════════╩════════╩════════════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySql ???

Comment: I'm sorry, this is SQL-Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `conditional Aggregate` will work in both `Mysql` and `Sql Server`

```
select 
max(case when ProgramTypeName = 'Center' then TypeAmount END) as Center
max(case when ProgramTypeName = 'School' then TypeAmount END) as School
From (select ProgramTypeName ,Count(ProgramTypeName) from x ...) A
Group by somecol
```

Comment: I think that the problem with this answer would be that TypeAmount isn't a row in a table it's a Count(ProgramTypeName)

Comment: This gives me sort of what I'm looking for other than it gives a table with Center and Home column, but it shows NULL values three times for each one, will provide an example of the result in original post.

Comment: @SandroPerez - Add `ProgName` in `group by`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, would you like me to post the Query I'm using?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work with this,

```
Select Max(Case When A.ProgName = 'Center'  Then TypeAmount End) As Center,
       Max(Case When A.ProgName = 'School'  Then TypeAmount End) As School,
       Max(Case When A.ProgName = 'Other'   Then TypeAmount End) As Other
From T_Prog P Inner Join (Select ProgID,
                                 ProgName, 
                                 Count(ProgName) As ProgAmount 
                          From T_ProgType_Join PTJ Inner Join T_ProgramType PTJ On PT.ProgramTypeId = PT.ProgramTypeId 
                          Where PTJ.ProgramId = @ProgID
                          Group by ProgName, ProgID) A On A.ProgID= P.ProgID
Where PTJ.ProgID= @ProgID
```

Answer (score 0):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ProgrameTypeName VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
 ('Central'),('Central'),('Central'),('Central')
,('School'),('School')
```

### Query

```
SELECT *
FROM @Table t
        PIVOT (
               COUNT(ProgrameTypeName)
               FOR ProgrameTypeName
               IN ([Central],[School])
              )p
```

### Result

```
╔═════════╦════════╗
║ Central ║ School ║
╠═════════╬════════╣
║    4    ║   2    ║
╚═════════╩════════╝
```